# htaccess don't rewrite to index for any URL

Tags: .htaccess

My htaccess don't rewrite to index HTML

https://world-of-easy-decisions.com/login

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Exclude rewriting for URLs starting with /main/
  RewriteRule ^main/ - [L]

  # Rewrite /login to index.html
  RewriteRule ^login$ index.html [L]

  # Rewrite all other requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the rewrite module enabled?

Comment: The link you give (to your website?) seems to be working OK? Is that not `index.html` that renders the response? What response are you expecting? (Although your site is not generating 404 responses... you are getting a 200 OK and client-side "redirect" to `/login`.)

Comment: Thanks Gerald was not enabled in the conf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the rewrite module is enabled.

Since you are using the `<IfModule>` directive, Apache will just ignore everything inside it if the module is not loaded and you will not receive any error messages regarding ths.

If your application relies on the rewrite module, it is best to not use the `<IfModule>` directive, so you can catch such errors during startup/restart/configtest.

How to enable the module depends on the distribution you are running Apache on and how it was installed.

Comment: It's the answer, as confirmed in the comments.

Comment: After the edits, yea.